# How can I specify optional characters in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression.

```
MMM D[,] YYYY   
/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\ (\d{2})\, (\d{4})$/
```

How i can do this [,] is optional?

```
MMM D, YYYY
MMM D YYYY
```

Comment: Here's a good reference for future regex questions you may have: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Just like the answers below stated. ? is what you are looking for. Here are some proof of concept: http://rubular.com/r/hO3sFQQE1V

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just do `,?` that makes the comma optional.

Answer (score 5):

Have not tested the rest of your expression, but placing a `?` after the comma will allow it 0 or 1 times.  If you want to allow multiple commas you would use a `*` which is 0 to infinite times.

Answer (score 3):

A question mark after a character makes it optional in regex.